# Using NeverBounce to validate email

Tags: vb.net

I am using this snippet to validate my NeverBounce account:

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

    Dim nb As NeverBounceSdk = New NeverBounceSdk("secret_.......")
    Dim rsp As AccountInfoResponseModel = nb.Account.Info().Result
    txtRes.Text = rsp.ToString
End Sub
```

But I do not get a response.  Based on the NeverBounce documentation, this appears to be the correct approach.  Do you know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Async methods must be used.  See the following.

```
Public Async Function IsValidAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim val As SingleResponseModel = Await ValidateAddressAsync()
    Return If(val.result = "valid", True, False)
End Function
Private Async Function ValidateAddressAsync() As Task(Of SingleResponseModel)
    Dim nb As NeverBounceSdk = New NeverBounceSdk("NeverBounce key")
    Dim mdl As New SingleRequestModel With {.email = FullAddress, .timeout = 30}
    Return Await nb.Single.Check(mdl)
End Function
```